# How to correct poor performance in T-SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is using a T-SQL view I created as part of its data model. I'm able to pull in the view data but I'm getting very poor performance.

If I do a `SELECT *` on the view in SQL Server 2008 it takes over 20 minutes to return all 187,101 of the rows.

If I do a `SELECT TOP 1000000` on the view I get the same 187,101 rows returned in 2 seconds.

So I included the `TOP` statement in my view design to try to get better performance in the ASP.NET MVC application but it still takes ~6 seconds to load the results in a WebGrid.

There's obviously something in my view design that is killing performance but I'm not sure how to fix it. I read about clustered index views but I can't schema bind the view because the tables need to be able to be modified.

Here is the `SELECT` statement I used to create my view:

```
SELECT TRD.Description AS Pbm,
       MV.ExtractHistoryMemberValueId,
       MV.FieldDescription,
       MV.FieldValue,
       HM.ExtractHistoryMemberId,
       HM.CaseNum,
       HM.CertNum,
       HM.ClmtNum,
       HM.PlanNum,
       EH.ExtractHistoryId,
       EH.ExtractDate
FROM OutgoingAccumulators.ExtractHistoryMemberValues AS MV
    INNER JOIN OutgoingAccumulators.ExtractHistoryMembers AS HM
        ON (MV.ExtractHistoryMember = HM.ExtractHistoryMemberId)
    INNER JOIN OutgoingAccumulators.ExtractHistories AS EH
        ON (HM.ExtractHistory = EH.ExtractHistoryId)
    INNER JOIN OutgoingAccumulators.Extracts AS EX
        ON (EH.Extract = EX.ExtractId)
    INNER JOIN Accumulators.Interfaces AS INF
        ON (EX.Interface = INF.InterfaceId)
    INNER JOIN Accumulators.TradingPartners AS TRD
        ON (INF.TradingPartner = TRD.TradingPartnerId)
```

Here is an image of the view design:

[image: view]

Comment: Are there indexes on all the fields being joined upon? Do you REALLY need all the columns?

Comment: @MarkCanlas Unfortunately, I really do have to grab all of these columns. I'm not 100% sure about the index portion of your question; there are primary/foreign key relationships on each field being joined.

Comment: FKs imply indexes, so the answer is yes. I would try do start your queries with just the base table and then tack on one join at a time to see where your query begins to suffer. Is there any lock contention going on, simultaneous reads and writes to the same tables? Are you chaining together multiple one-to-many queries?

Comment: Side question:  Why do you need 187000 rows in a grid view?  That's a lot of data to push from the server...

Comment: What about linking up the view with a grid control like Telerik RadGrid? It's got pretty smart handling of paging for large datasets, it might help the performance some.

Comment: It is going to take a few seconds to load 187,101 into a WebGrid.

Comment: The WebGrid is performing efficient paging via ajax. It's currently only retrieving 25 rows at a time. But the web performance is still effected by the raw view performance.

Comment: OK, need to get the query ajax is sending and view the query plan.  Top X is not really the way to fix your view.  Most likely the top x is causing a different type of join.  See what that is and put the join type (hash, loop, merge) in the view.

Comment: @MarkCanlas - FK imply indexes, but they aren't automatically put on by default. See of the other SO posts on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650713/685760) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2979826/685760)

Comment: Please post an "Actual Execution Plan" for this query.  There's a very limited amount that we can do without this information.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Here's the execution plan: http://i.imgur.com/Jvc0pMn.png

Comment: @Splendor I am looking at it now, do you have one the the TOP version of your query also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I added a non-clustered index to the ExtractHistoryMemberValues table like this:

```
USE [ProcessingDB]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ExtractHistoryMember]
ON [OutgoingAccumulators].[ExtractHistoryMemberValues] ([ExtractHistoryMember])
INCLUDE ([ExtractHistoryMemberValueId],[FieldDescription],[FieldValue])
GO
```

The view now returns all of the rows in under 2 seconds.

Here is the new execution plan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr3IJ.png